# MongoDB projection sort by string length in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a dictionary Database with meanings in an array called "germanTranslations". I want to get terms starting with a certain substring and sort them by the string-length of the result. (For search bar auto completion.)

For example:

```
{id:0, germanTranslations:["Diagnosekit","Testkit"]}
{id:1, germanTranslations:["Ausprobieren", "Testen", "Probe", "Test", "Versuch"]}
{id:2, germanTranslations:["Testament","Bibel"]}
```

And I want the result to project to

```
{id:1, germanTranslations: "Test"}
{id:1, germanTranslations: "Testen"}
{id:0, germanTranslations: "Testkit"}
{id:2, germanTranslations: "Testament"}
```

I tried using this syntax (currently only using Compass)

```
Filter: {germanTranslations:{$regex:/^test/i}}
Project: {"germanTranslations":1,"result_length":{$strLenCP: "germanTranslations.$"}}
Sort: {"result_length":1}
```

which treats "germanTranslations.$" as a literal string, but "$germanTranslations.$" gives me a syntax error and "$germanTranslations" is an array and not a string. I tried using arrayElemAt, but I don't know how i can get the index of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected result which deconstructs the `germanTranslations` array into multiple documents requires the `$unwind` stage. This should be done in the aggregation pipeline.

1. `$match`
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `germanTranslations` array into multiple documents.
3. `$match` - Filter the regex-matched documents.
4. `$project`
5. `$sort`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      germanTranslations: {
        $regex: "^test",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$germanTranslations"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      germanTranslations: {
        $regex: "^test",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "germanTranslations": 1,
      "result_length": {
        $strLenCP: "$germanTranslations"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "result_length": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AEszvK0omx0)